# Library to read input from keyboard-recognized RFID reader

Tags: node.js, usb, rfid

I have a RFID reader that gets recognised as a keyboard when plugged in the computer so if I approach a tag to the reader, the tag's code will be written wherever I have a cursor like a text editor or whatever.

I've been trying to make a simple app that can read the reader's input, since the RFID reader writes to the stdin I want to use it with an app to accomplish various things.

I tried [node-usb](https://github.com/nonolith/node-usb) but throws a weird NOT FOUND error, see [issue #32](https://github.com/nonolith/node-usb/issues/32) and [node-hid](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid) but the `on data` event never get's triggered, see [issue #54](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/issues/54).

Any ideas what can be the problem or what other solutions or libraries can be helpful? (node.js ones preferably)

Comment: Could you please share some info on the device? Manufacturer/site/specs or whatnot.

Comment: It seems like a generic: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00GOLXKA6

Comment: Did you try checking with [serialport](https://npmjs.org/package/serialport)?

Comment: I will try it tonight and let you know. Thank you @bredikhin